# can not access my wordpress dashboard, when i clicked on each dashboard pageit shows me 404 bad request error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I don't know why, but I can't access my `WordPress` dashboard. I'm using the latest version.

What I've tried so far: I've checked permissions in the database - everything is ok, Prefix in the database is ok, I've removed `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` and I've uploaded new files from the latest version.

Error : [image: 1]

Comment: More details? Hosting? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The 400 Bad Request Error is an HTTP response status code that indicates that the server was unable to process the request sent by the client due to invalid syntax

contact to host manager

also this may help to you

1)Clear Relevant Cookies

2)Uninstall New Extensions, Modules, or Plugins

3)Look Through the Logs

4)Log Out and Log In

Answer (score 0):

Please give the writable permission on both directories and remove "w3tc-config" directory from "/wp-content/" if you have used "w3 total cache plugin"
Access wp-admin using below URL:
https://yourdomain.com/wp-login.php

Please share website URL so we can better assist you.

Comment: kvgvm.in is domain name

Comment: Please use the below login URL to access dashboard/backend using wp-admin credentials.
http://kvgvm.in/login/
I think you have used a plugin to modify login URL for security purpose.

Comment: if the issue still exists, restore database and source code and upgrade WordPress and plugins from the backend or rename plugins folder and test step by step. I hope this will resolve the issue.

Comment: can you please help me to solved this issue.. please .. just give me your mail id.. i will create one zoom meeting.. please help me to solved this

Comment: NP, kanhaiya.yaduwanshi@galaxyweblinks.in 
Please try to host zoom meeting before 11 AM (IST)